# Troubleshooting websites on gaming consoles

Tags: html, javascript, cross-platform, debug

I realize that questions like "suggest a tool" are usually not allowed, but I would like to pick your brains for a good way to troubleshoot websites on gaming consoles (PS3/4 , Xbox360/One and others).

Since the browsers that come with these platforms have limited developers tools, what's a good way to collect information about Requests, Responses, Resources, JavaScript and so on?

I've been using User Agent emulators, like Agent Switcher, in the past with a lot of success. However, I stumbled across a problem that requires me to step into a JavaScript script code and see it execute step by step on PS4.

Comment: If that's a practically market that is valuable and important then the best way to test it is actually on a real device. Emu's should never be treated as a 'FINAL' testing solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I settled on App Debugger (http://debug-software.intel.com/) from Intel. It was simplest and straight forward way to stream debug information from a device.

Answer (score 4):

I think the solution you're looking is a HTTP debuging proxy like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler). You could then set the console's proxy settings to point to the computer running Fiddler. From there, you'll be able to view all requests and all responses.

I don't think it will work properly with https sites since Fiddler installs a cert on the machine but the console will still see a certificate error.

Comment: Your answer is great too, but it needs a bit more installation and setup. It might be useful for those users that are experienced and comfortable with Fiddler.